# Python script inside bash script. How to not print log error on console?

Tags: python, bash, logging

I have a python script running inside a bash script as below:

```
var=$(python <<EOF
try:
  import sys
  import gflags
  var = Dummy.get_dummy_var()
  if var == so_n_so:
    print "found"
  else:
    print "unknown"
except Exception as e:
  pass
EOF
)
```

Inside get_dummy_var() there is a `log.ERROR("some log error message")`. This is printed in the log file. Also, it is getting printed on the console where the above bash script is run as follows:

```
ERROR:root:some log error message
```

I do not want the above log error message on the console. How can I achieve this?

UPDATE 1:
`log` is a wrapper over python `logging`

Answer (score 0):

- One way is to redirect logs to [`NullHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) (python >= 3.1)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

var=$(python3 <<EOF
import logging
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.NullHandler()])
print("usefull text")
logging.getLogger().critical("critical")
logging.getLogger().error("an error")
logging.getLogger().info("a message")
EOF
)

echo "var is: $var"
```

- Or for python2:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

var=$(python2 <<EOF
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="/dev/null")
print("usefull text")
logging.getLogger().critical("critical")
logging.getLogger().error("an error")
logging.getLogger().info("a message")
EOF
)

echo "var is: $var"
```

- By default python only log errors and criticals to stderr, so you can redirect stderr:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

var=$(python3 <<EOF 2>/dev/null
import logging
print("usefull text")
logging.getLogger().critical("critical")
logging.getLogger().error("an error")
logging.getLogger().info("a message")
EOF
)

echo "var is: $var"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I need the output of the python script in var. Though I do not see the error message on console now, this is not populating the variable `var`. `echo "var is: $var"` prints `var is: ` on the console.

Comment: In each case you should have `var is: usefull text`.
ps: NullHandler is only available with python >= 3.1, not in py2

Comment: I am currently using Python 2.7. Can u suggest something for py2? Changing the code to py3 is in progress, but need this in py2 now.

Comment: `basicConfig(filename="/dev/null")` work with python 2.7
Hoping that you don't have any other logging configuration in the imports.